# How to pass data from StartPage (_ViewStart.cshtml) to Layout.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my layout page, I have a banner that I only want to show at Staging environment. How can I have it hidden automatically once deployed to Production?

In `_ViewStart.cshtml`, I can use `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("web_env")` to obtain the needed info, but how to hide the `div` in the layout page? I can't return a `ActionResult` like in the controllers, can I?

`<div id='warning'>blah</div>`

**UPDATE**

In `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
PageData["IsProd"] = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("web_env") == "PROD";
```

In `Layout.cshtml`:

```
@if (!PageData["IsProd"])
{
    <div id="warning">
        you are in testing environment.
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional statement and set a value in AppSettings in your web.config

```
@if(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsDev"] == "1")
{
   <div id='warning'>blah</div>
}
```

or

```
@if(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("web_env") == "0")
{
   <div id='warning'>blah</div>
}
```

Comment: is there a way to pass that variable from `ViewStart`?

Comment: Pass to "Layout.cshtml" from "_ViewStart.cshtml".

Comment: I got it. In `_ViewStart.cshtml`: `this.PageData["IsProd"] = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("web_env") == "PROD";` then in `Layout.cshtml`: `@if (this.PageData["IsProd"]) { //blah blah}`

Answer (score 1):

In your View:

```
@if(isNotProductionEnvironment)
{
    <div id='warning'>This will be visible anywhere but production</div>
}
```